# Is it required to differentiate between js framework and js library?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, libraries

While searching through many javascript libraries/frameworks, I observed that the terms are sometimes used interchangeably.

So, conceptually is it important to distinguish between framework and library?

Do people seriously make their decisions based on whether it is a library or framework?

Would a user like to browse two separate areas - libraries and frameworks while looking for a solution?

Comment: I'd say the answer is no, but this has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576018/what-is-the-difference-between-a-javascript-framework-and-a-library

Comment: A framework does inversion of control. A library does not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148747/what-is-the-difference-between-a-framework-and-a-library

Comment: @user814064, Benjamin - I can differentiate between two; My only concern is - do the community care about this differentiation?

Comment: Thanks for your great post.
I also refer very helpful article about Javascript framework and library.
Visit this helpful article about [Javascript framework and library](http://www.mindstick.com/blog/636/Javascript%20framework%20and%20library#.Vgjjv5c0Xcc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, conceptually is it important to distinguish between framework and library?

Yes, it is. A framework and a library are *fundamentally* different. The defining characteristic of a framework is *inversion of control*: when you use a library, *you* call the library; when you use a framework, the *framework* calls you.

So, they are not just "different", they are in fact exact opposites in some sense.

> Do people seriously make their decisions based on whether it is a library or framework?

Yes, of course. Building a solution with a library vs. a framework yields completely different (again, in some sense *opposite*) design. With a framework, the entire structure of your code will be "inside-out" compared to with a library.

> Would a user like to browse two separate areas - libraries and frameworks while looking for a solution?

Highly likely. I know I would.